# Using ArrayFormula with Lookup functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

PS: Using Google Sheets

I have a Google Sheet that is populated by Google forms, and I'm looking to use this data to make a new sheet with the values when the column type is a particular value.

For ex, here are a few rows of my data:

```
Name    Date        Type        Reference No
John    10/11/2022  SSS         551200550
Peter   10/11/2022  Transfer    510568810
John    10/11/2022  SSS         5105688415
Peter   10/11/2022  Other       510568851
```

Now, I have 1000s of rows, and I want to make a new sheet for each 'type' (In the example it's SSS and Transfer, but I have a few different types)

Ex 1: For SSS, here is the sheet, and accordingly for other values in 'Type', it should go into another sheet

```
Name    Date        Type    Reference No
John    10/11/2022  SSS     551200550
John    10/11/2022  SSS     5105688415
```

Essentially, I want to pull data from the master data and want to create a new sheet for each different type. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be using =ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet!A:A, IF(...)) or if I'm meant to use it with VLOOKUP.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

Tried with =ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet!A:A, IF(..)) but didn't get anywhere, looking for any help

Comment: Please provide test data with before and desired after plus your current output.

Comment: @CodeCamper Updated with data

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I believe your goal `to create a new sheet for each different type` is not possible when using Google sheets formula alone. Google Apps Script is recommended in achieving this goal. If you wish `to pull data from the master data` using Google sheets formula alone, then the other sheets should already be present.

Comment: `create a new sheet for each <whatever>`  is a really bad idea. It is unmanageable as the types grow.

Comment: You might be looking to use a QUERY. Give a try, it's very simple to set the condition you want, and then comeback here if you're stuck.